# Flash does not start automatically in Fancybox anymore

Tags: flash, fancybox, microsoft-edge, windows-update

I use Fancybox for displaying Flash content (just graphs, no animations). After the Windows 10 Anniversary update, I am having this very specific problem:

1. The first Fancybox popup with Flash on a page is displayed normally
2. With every subsequent popup on the same page, I have to move or click the mouse before the content is displayed.
3. The problem exists only with Microsoft Edge, not with Internet Explorer.

This example shows the issue:
http://www.esims.nl/weblog/2016/08/flash_test.html

I would also like to mention the strange behaviour of Edge when right-clicking on a Fancybox popup, and selecting 'Inspect element'. It opens an increasing number of windows every time you do this.  Check this on the Fancybox examples page:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

There might be a link between these issues. Anyhow, I'd like to know if there is a way to display the Flash content in Fancybox, in Edge, automatically again.

Comment: The second issue is a known bug, with a fix in the pipeline. Do you have a repro of the first issue though? I'm an engineer on the Edge team, and would love to assist you in finding a solution/work-around.

Comment: This is a repro of the first issue:
http://www.esims.nl/weblog/2016/08/flash_test.html